# Install libraries in a different dir

Tags: python, windows, pygame

I want to install pygame on my system, but I don't want to mix the standard libraries with third-party libs. If I install pygame on a different path, how can I then modify `sys.path` so the interpreter would know where to look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) to a directory with additional modules. And if you use Python 2.6 or newer, you can just use [the default per-user module directory](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-370-per-user-site-packages-directory) without additional configuration.

Answer (score 4):

It may be overkill, but did you consider using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html)? It would let you have a virtual Python installation that used the standard for everything except the libraries you want to keep separate.

Comment: Wasn't there a way to modify PATH in Windows, or something?

Comment: `PATH` doesn't relate to `sys.path`

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this trick:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"..")

import pygame # it will look for pygame in ../ first.
```

Comment: Oops, i guess you wanted to **install** to another dir, not to read it from another dir. :-/